# Logout from service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm currently logging in with a username and password this way:

```
var client = new ServiceReference.CalcServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test";
client.DoWork();
```

This works fine. Now, I'd like to add a way to logout (the user presses a button and a logout request should be send somehow).

Is this possible and if so, what would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: Please, provide more details - is CalcServiceClient is just Proxy? So may be it'll be good enough to close it?

Comment: Since WCF is stateless (or at least should be) there is no concept of session. The credentials are saved in the proxy instance and each request is authenticated separately. If there is a different behavior for this specific service, tell us what it is and maybe we can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the WCF is configured PerSession, a `client.Close();` will do the work.

The process will be:

- The client creates the proxy of the WCF service and makes method
  calls.
- A WCF service instance is created which serves the method response.
- The client makes one more method call in the same session.
- The same WCF service instance serves the method call.
- When the client finishes its activity, the WCF instance is destroyed
  and served to the garbage collector for clean up.

With the Close you will trigger the garbage collector clean up.

If the WCF is configured PerCall, there is no need to worry about Close/Logof. I would recommend always perform an explicit Close (and an using), but it's not really necessary in that case.

If the WCF is configured SingleInstance... well, maybe you are doing it wrong :) anyway, you should proceed with a Close().